# How to get current time with milliseconds

Tags: time, tcl, milliseconds

I am using TCL 8.6 version and trying to "get current time with milliseconds" using TCL.

Output I am willing to get is as below: using example time

```
11:06:52.123
```

Answer (score 13):

```
set t [clock milliseconds]
set timestamp [format "%s.%03d" \
                  [clock format [expr {$t / 1000}] -format %T] \
                  [expr {$t % 1000}] \
              ]
```

---

Looking back at this, I'd use a helper proc to tidy things up:

```
proc divmod {numerator divisor} {
    list [expr {$numerator / $divisor}] [expr {$numerator % $divisor}]
}

lassign [divmod [clock milliseconds] 1000] sec milli
set timestamp [format {%s.%03d} [clock format $sec -format %T] $milli]
```